# Typehead.js - Cuts off length of input field

Tags: javascript, css

I am using typeahead.js. When using it with bootstrap 5, my input field shrinks.

Find below my example:

```js
   var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substringRegex;

            // an array that will be populated with substring matches
            matches = [];

            // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

            // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
            // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
            $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
                if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                    matches.push(str);
                }
            });

            cb(matches);
        };
    };

    var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
        'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
        'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
        'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
        'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
        'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
        'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
        'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
        'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
    ];

    $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'states',
            source: substringMatcher(states)
        });
```

```css
span.twitter-typeahead .tt-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu,
span.twitter-typeahead .tt-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #373a3c;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

span.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion {
  /* display: block; */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #373a3c;
  text-align: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
}

span.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion:focus,
.dropdown-item:hover,
span.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion:hover {
  color: #2b2d2f;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

span.twitter-typeahead .active.tt-suggestion,
span.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor,
span.twitter-typeahead .active.tt-suggestion:focus,
span.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor:focus,
span.twitter-typeahead .active.tt-suggestion:hover,
span.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0275d8;
  outline: 0;
}

span.twitter-typeahead .disabled.tt-suggestion,
span.twitter-typeahead .disabled.tt-suggestion:focus,
span.twitter-typeahead .disabled.tt-suggestion:hover {
  color: #818a91;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-qOBWNAMfkz+vXXgbh0Wz7qYSLZp6c14R0bZeVX2TdQxWpuKr6yHjBIM69fcF8Ve4GUX6B6AKRQJqiiAmwvmUmQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://min.gitcdn.link/repo/Codekutu/Bootstrap4TagsInputWithTypeahead/master/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>

<body>
  <main class="container pt-3">

    <div class="row mt-3">
      <form name="watchlistForm" id="watchlistForm" method="POST" action="">
        <div id="error"></div>
        <div id="the-basics">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="text" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="Add your Email">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input class="form-control typeahead" name="symbols" id="symbols" type="text" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="Pick the symbols that you want to monitor">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" id="listBtn">Add to List</button>
            <small class="w-100 text-muted">Pick the product that you want to monitor.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="symbolPicks" name="symbolPicks"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Subscribe</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to look my form the following way:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My form is not as long as the email input field above. Why?

I found that if I add the javascript code part, my form is cut-off.

I really appreciate your replies!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdxK1.png

Answer (score 1):

Just add `flex-grow:1` to your `span.twitter-typeahead`. It's all about how flexbox and flex children work.

Read more about [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```js
var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substringRegex;

            // an array that will be populated with substring matches
            matches = [];

            // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

            // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
            // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
            $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
                if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                    matches.push(str);
                }
            });

            cb(matches);
        };
    };

    var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
        'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
        'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
        'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
        'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
        'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
        'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
        'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
        'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
    ];

    $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'states',
            source: substringMatcher(states)
        });
```

```css
   span.twitter-typeahead {
   flex-grow: 1;
   }

span.twitter-typeahead .tt-menu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu,
span.twitter-typeahead .tt-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #373a3c;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

span.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion {
  /* display: block; */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #373a3c;
  text-align: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
}

span.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion:focus,
.dropdown-item:hover,
span.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion:hover {
  color: #2b2d2f;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

span.twitter-typeahead .active.tt-suggestion,
span.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor,
span.twitter-typeahead .active.tt-suggestion:focus,
span.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor:focus,
span.twitter-typeahead .active.tt-suggestion:hover,
span.twitter-typeahead .tt-suggestion.tt-cursor:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0275d8;
  outline: 0;
}

span.twitter-typeahead .disabled.tt-suggestion,
span.twitter-typeahead .disabled.tt-suggestion:focus,
span.twitter-typeahead .disabled.tt-suggestion:hover {
  color: #818a91;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-qOBWNAMfkz+vXXgbh0Wz7qYSLZp6c14R0bZeVX2TdQxWpuKr6yHjBIM69fcF8Ve4GUX6B6AKRQJqiiAmwvmUmQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://min.gitcdn.link/repo/Codekutu/Bootstrap4TagsInputWithTypeahead/master/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>

<body>
  <main class="container pt-3">

    <div class="row mt-3">
      <form name="watchlistForm" id="watchlistForm" method="POST" action="">
        <div id="error"></div>
        <div id="the-basics">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="text" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="Add your Email">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input class="form-control typeahead" name="symbols" id="symbols" type="text" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="Pick the symbols that you want to monitor">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" id="listBtn">Add to List</button>
            <small class="w-100 text-muted">Pick the product that you want to monitor.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="symbolPicks" name="symbolPicks"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Subscribe</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```